# (C# using WPF) Saving and retrieving multiple entries of data onto a txt file

Tags: c#, wpf

[UI for browsing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liSoY.png)

Im lookig for a  way to save and open multiple entries of data from the text boxes onto a .txt file. By "multiple entries" I mean having a kind of database of (in this instance) members of a certain team, without the use of LINQ. So for example having Messi and his data as the first entry, then when I press "Next", the second player would appear along with their data.

Currently I am using the SaveFileDialog and OpenFileDialog method to save and open entries, however it only saves a single record.

```
        private void menu_save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            using (StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(File.Create(sfd.FileName)))
            {
                write.WriteLine(tbox_name.Text);
                write.WriteLine(tbox_dob.Text);
                write.WriteLine(tbox_number.Text);
                write.WriteLine(tbox_nationality.Text);
                write.WriteLine(tbox_height.Text);
                write.WriteLine(tbox_weight.Text);
                write.WriteLine(tbox_position.Text);
                write.Close();
                write.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

        private void menu_open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(ofd.FileName)))
            {
                tbox_name.Text = read.ReadLine();
                tbox_dob.Text = read.ReadLine();
                tbox_number.Text = read.ReadLine();
                tbox_nationality.Text = read.ReadLine();
                tbox_height.Text = read.ReadLine();
                tbox_weight.Text = read.ReadLine();
                tbox_position.Text = read.ReadLine();
                read.Close();
                read.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
```

[.txt file after saving data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYBkV.png)

I would like the application to be able to save, for example, 11 entries (players) on a single .txt file and be able to go through the "database" with the 'Next' and 'Previous' buttons. I would also like to have an option to sort the players in an alphabetical order. Any help would be much appreciated as Im new to WPF and havent quite gotten my head around it yet.

Comment: hello, can you please give any feedback on the answer I have posted?

Answer (score 0):

`File.Create` overwrites existing file (all previous data gets lost). Use [`File.AppendAllLines` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383691(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void menu_save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    if (sfd.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        File.AppendAllLines(sfd.FileName, new string []
        {
            tbox_name.Text,
            tbox_dob.Text,
            tbox_number.Text,
            tbox_nationality.Text,
            tbox_height.Text,
            tbox_weight.Text,
            tbox_position.Text,
        });
    }
}
```

similarly to read all data use `File.ReadAllLines` method, but you will have to separate lines into groups after that:

```
string[] lines;
int index;
private void menu_open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        lines = File.ReadAllLines(ofd.FileName);
        index = 0;
        Display(index);            
    }
}

private void Display(int number)
{
    int i = number * 7; // 7 is a number of values per item
    tbox_name.Text = lines[i];
    tbox_dob.Text = lines[i+1];
    tbox_number.Text = lines[i+2];
    tbox_nationality.Text = lines[i+3];
    tbox_height.Text = lines[i+4];
    tbox_weight.Text = lines[i+5];
    tbox_position.Text = lines[i+6];    
}
```

to display next, do `index++; Display(index);`

to display previous, do `index--; Display(index);`